# Running the three.js editor from local files

Tags: three.js, editor

I recently downloaded the three.js-master files which included the three.js editor. How do you run the editor from the files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Ensure `node.js` is installed.
- Open a console and navigate to the root directory of the repository.
- Execute `npm i` to install package and its dependencies.
- Start a local dev server via `npm start`.
- Open the editor via `http://localhost:8080/editor/`.

Comment: It gives me an error when I type in "npm start"

Comment: What error? Please be more specific.

Comment: npm ERR! missing script: start

Comment: Your are probably in the wrong directory. The `start` script does exist: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/6658460bf092ce0e931f34b0d71f2b289ab143c2/package.json#L72